# Difference between NSOperationQueue: currentQueue/new?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between those 2.

Does it mean `currentQueue` cannot be `mainQueue` or it's a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentQueue` return `mainQueue` if you call it in main-thread.
`new` is new queue with new threads

Comment: Then 'new' will run on background?

Answer (score 2):

`new` is initializer method which `NSOperationQueue` inherits from `NSObject`

Documentation says:

> This method is a combination of `alloc` and `init`. Like `alloc`, it initializes the isa instance variable of the new object so it points to the class data structure. It then invokes the init method to complete the initialization process.

This means calling `+new` creates new instance of `NSOperationQueue`

---

`currentQueue` returns you the queue on which the method was called.

`NSOperationQueue` docs of `currentQueue` says:

> The operation queue that started the operation or nil if the queue could not be determined

I.e. if method calling `+currentQueue` is `mainQueue`, it can return `mainQueue`

Answer (score 1):

prove of concept write by @Cy-4AH. Hop this can clarify a bit.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^(void){
        //this block will executed in a separate thread (not the main thread)
        if ([NSOperationQueue currentQueue] == [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]) {
            NSLog(@"= in block");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"not = in block"); //This will be log
        }
    }];



    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [operationQueue addOperation:blockOperation];

    //this block will executed in the main thread
    if ([NSOperationQueue currentQueue] == [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]) {
        NSLog(@"= outside of block"); //This will be log
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not = outside of block");
    }

}
```